# Will ZlibEx work for Delphi 10 Seattle?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I am missing a ZlibEx unit in my code. Can I used the ZlibEx library from [Mike Lischke's GraphicEx library](https://github.com/mike-lischke/GraphicEx/tree/master/3rd%20party/DelphiZlib)?  The [Base2 Technologies site](http://www.base2ti.com/) mentions the library is only for "*Delphi 5, 6, 7, 8, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2010, xe, xe2, and xe3*".

Can I use it for Delphi 10 Seattle?

Comment: What is XE10? The XE names stopped at 8, and the next version released was Delphi 10 Seattle.

Comment: Sorry I meant Delphi 10 Seattle only

Comment: And when I read the help its actually there in DELPHI 10 then why "cannot resolve unit ZlibEx"?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this ZlibEx library? What is wrong with the System.ZLib RTL unit bound with Delphi 10 Seattle?

Comment: What happened when you tried to use it in Delphi 10?

Comment: Yes its working fine. As I am saying I am very new to the language and the terminolagies. I had crested A package and installed it.

Comment: If you're using Seattle, unless ZLibEx has some special features in it, you might want to port to using TZipFile instead, as it's part of the RTL now. It would remove the external dependency, and you wouldn't have to ask this sort of question when the next version is released. (Of course, the correct thing to do would have been to just compile it to find out if it would work; it would have been faster than posting a question here.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the ZlibEx unit was created to bring a newer version of the [ZLIB](http://zlib.net/) library into Delphi, since at the time the version that was shipping with the VCL was an older version and was missing some needed functionality.

Delphi 10 Seattle now has been updated to use the latest version of ZLIB, so you might be able to just use RTL ZLIB instead of ZLibEx. If I remember correctly, there were a few extra wrapper routines in ZlibEx that may not have a counterpart, but those should be easy to migrate over into your code.

Answer (score -1):

> Can I use it for Delphi 10 Seattle?

Yes.

The code compiles in Delphi 10 Seattle and I see no reason why it will not work. The text that lists the supported compiler versions is simply out of date and has not been updated since the release of XE3.

Comment: I feel bad about answering this question. All the asker had to do was compile the code! @Siddharth, why not try harder in the future?

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not sure what you didn't like about the answer, but is the edit better?

Comment: What I didn't like about the answer was the single line quote from the OP and a single *Yes* as the entire content. So yes, your edit is much better.